# Convert data frame with one column into txt documents (one txt document per row)

Tags: r, tm

I need to convert a data frame with one column into txt documents (one txt document per row) so that I can use the tm package , which needs a corpus.  I tried using the strsplit function, but nothing I tried has worked.  Here is some example data:

```
Descriptions_of_Procedure (column name)
Anesthesia for lower leg cast application
Anesthesia for face
Anesthesia for upper leg
Dressing change
```

Comment: Please consider that a small reproductible example is appreciated. You can for exemple prepare some minimal data frame example that can help us to answer faster

Answer (score 1):

```
df<-data.frame(Descriptions_of_Procedure =c(
                  "Anesthesia for lower leg cast application",
                  "Anesthesia for face",
                  "Anesthesia for upper leg",
                  "Dressing change"))



for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  write.csv(df[i,],paste0("line",i,".txt"),row.names=FALSE)
}
```

This will create one txt file by row in which there is only one row of the `df` data frame

#### Edit : suppress the name of the column in the file

Use `write.table()` instead of `write.csv()` and you can provide the function with `col.names = FALSE` and then have only the `row i` written in the document `line i`

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  write.table(df[i,],paste0("line",i,".txt"),row.names=FALSE,col.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: thanks, and sorry about not providing an example dataframe.  When I follow your code I get an extra "x" printed on the first line of each txt document.  Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: I think the x is the name of the column try to suppress it in the `write.csv()` function

Answer (score 0):

The `DataframeSource()` function of the `tm` package was designed for this.

```
library(tm)
# code from here
# example(DataframeSource)
docs <- data.frame(c("This is a text.", "This another one."))
(ds <- DataframeSource(docs))
inspect(VCorpus(ds))
```

(The `V` in VCorpus is optional)